# Cache gets deleted every night when cron jobs are being executed

Tags: magento2, cache, cron

In my Magento 2.3.4 store the cache gets deleted every night at around 1. I figured that when I disable the calling of the cron.sh script, it does not happen. Is there a way to figure out why this is happening and what jobs are being executed around that time?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check "cron_schedule" table, so you get idea on that time which cron is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You may debug if there is any crontab defined to clear Magento 2 cache.

Run below command

**crontab -l**

Also, you may check if is there any custom modules that have cron defined to flush the Magento cache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the Cron Jobs Logs to find out, If any error occurs or issues at the specified time when Cron Jobs fires.

Also try to Check the Modules - If there is any Cron which cleans the Cache else you need to disable the added modules and check.

**To debug - Try the below**

- Check Magento Cron Job log/information at `<install_directory>/var/log/cron.log`
- Failed jobs with ERROR and MISSED statuses are logged to the `<install_directory>/var/log/support_report.log`
- Jobs with an ERROR status are always logged as CRITICAL in `<install_directory>/var/log/exception.log`
- Jobs with a MISSED status are logged as INFO in the `<install_directory>/var/log/debug.log directory (developer mode only)`

All cron data is also written to the `cron_schedule` table in the Magento database. The table provides a history of cron jobs, including:

1. Job ID and code Status
2. Created date
3. Scheduled date
4. Executed date
5. Finished date

To see records in the table, log in to the Magento database on the command line and enter `SELECT * from cron_schedule;`